# Derivative of integral bounds

Tags: integration, derivatives

how do I find the derivative of

[integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOaek.png)

[answer book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDtBo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous fonction with a partial derivative according to the first variable continuous and $a$ and $b$ two derivable functions.

The fonction $\displaystyle F(t) = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(t,\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau$ is derivable on  $\mathbb{R}$ and its derivative is given by:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} F(t) = \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau  + f(t,b(t))\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}b(t) - f(t,a(t))\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}a(t).
$$

In your case, on $\mathbb{R}_+$ the derivative is given by:
$$
u \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma^*\pi}}\frac{1}{u}\mathrm{e}^{-(\log(u/s)-m^*)/(2\sigma^*)}.
$$

Edit: if the square is missing in the initial integral, the derivative is of course given by:
$$
u \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\sigma^*\pi}}\frac{1}{u}\mathrm{e}^{-(\log(u/s)-m^*)^2/(2\sigma^*)}.
$$

Comment: Can you please see my edit? My solution book says the answer is slightly different, but your answer might be equivalent, I am not sure.

Comment: @EmilKrabbe I think there a typo in your book. Probably, the square is missing in the initial integral (assuming you are working with a Gaussian function no ?).